# syntax error: unexpected comma, expecting go

Tags: go, printing

So here is my code, and I can't print out x? And also can I have some advice for this program? I also would like to store the print out data as a CSV. file for every transaction happened. And also if you guys provided some link I would be appreciated.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {

    var coke int64 = 15
    var sprite int64 = 15
    var fanta int64 = 15
    var mirinda int64 = 15
    var mineralwater int64 = 8
    

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    
    fmt.Print("Coke anount : ")
    scanner.Scan()
    cokeAmount, _ := strconv.ParseInt(scanner.Text(), 10, 64)

    fmt.Print("Sprite Amount : ")
    scanner.Scan()
    spriteAmount, _ := strconv.ParseInt(scanner.Text(), 10, 64)

    fmt.Print("Fanta Amount : ")
    scanner.Scan()
    fantaAmount, _ := strconv.ParseInt(scanner.Text(), 10, 64)

    fmt.Print("Mirinda Amount : ")
    scanner.Scan()
    mirindaAmount, _ := strconv.ParseInt(scanner.Text(), 10, 64)

    fmt.Print("Mineral water Amount : ")
    scanner.Scan()
    miniralWaterAmount, _ := strconv.ParseInt(scanner.Text(), 10, 64)
    
        var price int64 = (coke * (cokeAmount)) + (sprite * (spriteAmount)) + (fanta * (fantaAmount)) + (mirinda * (mirindaAmount)) + (mineralwater * (miniralWaterAmount))
        fmt.Println("The total cost will be : ", price)

    fmt.Print("Cash received : ")
    scanner.Scan()
    mReceived, _ := strconv.ParseInt(scanner.Text(), 10, 64)

    var mReturn int64 = mReceived - price
    fmt.Print("Cash returned : ", mReturn)

    x = ((cokeAmount),(spriteAmount),(fantaAmount),(mirindaAmount),(miniralWaterAmount))
    fmt.Println(x)
    

}
```

Comment: The line where you assign `x` to something is not valid Go syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

line 51 should read

x := []int64{cokeAmount, spriteAmount, fantaAmount, mirindaAmount, miniralWaterAmount}